# Shifting a pixel image left and right

Tags: java

I have a set of arrays (which are "pixels" - RGB representation) for e.g.

```
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)
(2,2,2)(2,2,2)(2,2,2)(2,2,2)
```

I want to shift left/right the columns and up/down the rows. for example:

ShiftCol + 2 will yield the output:

```
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(2,2,2)(2,2,2)
```

ShiftRow - 1 will yield the output:(after ShiftCol +2)

```
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)
```

(what happend in the above output is: First row move to second row, second row to third row, and first row became black (just zero's), the third row is just replaced with the second row.

ShiftCol- 1 will yield the output:

```
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0)
(0,0,0)(1,1,1)(1,1,1)(0,0,0)
```

I just need your help to show me how can I "move" every column to the right, that will be enough. What I managed to do is when ShiftCol +2 is called, the first column is moved 2 columns to the right (and is appeared on the third column) and the first two columns are turned to (0,0,0) which is black color. the problem is I don't know how to move EVERY column to the right according the the number it is called to move right, for example - if i call ShiftCol(2) and the pixel image array is 3x4 as you can see in the outputs what should happen is that: first column will be moved twice to the right - to the third column, and first column will become black (0,0,0), second column will be moved to twice to the right too and will become the fourth column. third and fourth columns will just be replaced by first and second columns.

It'll be enough if you just guide me somehow how to manage that, anyhow you can focus on the method "ShiftCol" only in RGBImage class and you'll see what I've accomplished so far within code. Thanks on advance!

***PLEASE**, keep the answer simple with code. I learned just for loops, while loops, if statements, arrays.. I don't want to use in this project any other advanced material.

Here's my code:

RGBColor class:

```
public class RGBColor {
        /**
         * attributes: red, green and blue component of a color.
         */
        private int _red,_green,_blue;

        /**
         * final variables.
         */
        private final int MAX_VALUE = 255,MIN_VALUE = 0;
        private final double THIRTY_PERCENT = 0.3,FIFTY_NINE_PERCENT = 0.59,ELEVEN_PERCENT = 0.11;                   

        /**
         * Consctructor which gets 3 colors (RGB), we check here if their range is valid (0 - 255), if not we assign black to it.
         *
         *  @param red - The red color component value.
         *  @param green - The green color component value.
         *  @param blue - The blue color component value
         */
        public RGBColor(int red, int green, int blue)
        {
            if(isValid(red,green,blue))
            {
                _red   = red;
                _green = green;
                _blue  = blue;
            }
            else
                doBlack();
        }


        /**
         * Construct a black RGBColor. i.e. red = green = blue = 0
         */
        public RGBColor()
        {
        doBlack();
    }



    /**
     * Here we check if the color number was entered correctly.
     * It has to be an integer (whole number) between 0-255.
     * 
     * @param nums - a component value, should be the number between 1-4
     * @param return - return true if the number is between 1-4, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isValid(int nums)
    {
        return ((nums >= MIN_VALUE) && (nums <= MAX_VALUE));
    }

    /**
     * Here we check if the color number was entered correctly.
     * It has to be an integer (whole number) between 0-255.
     * 
     * @param red - the red component
     * @param green - the green component
     * @param blue - the red component
     * @param return true if values are correct, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isValid(int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        return ((red <= MAX_VALUE && red >= MIN_VALUE && 
                green <= MAX_VALUE && green >= MIN_VALUE &&
                blue <= MAX_VALUE && blue >= MIN_VALUE));
    }
    /**
     * Returns RGB color string triplet with numbers between 0-255, i.e. (0,127,127)
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return ("(" + _red + "," + _green + "," + _blue + ")");
    }

    /**
     * RGBColor will become the color Black. (0,0,0)
     */
    private void doBlack()
    {
        _red = _green = _blue = 0;
    }

}
```

RGBImage class:

```
public class RGBImage
{
  private int _rows, _cols;
 private RGBColor[][] _pixels;
 private int _offset = 0;

  public RGBImage(int rows, int cols)
{
  _rows = rows;
  _cols = cols;
  _pixels = new RGBColor[_rows][_cols];
  for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < _cols; j++)
        _pixels[i][j] = new RGBColor();
}

public RGBImage(RGBColor[][] pixels)
{
    _rows = pixels.length;
    _cols = pixels[0].length;
    _pixels = new RGBColor[_rows][_cols];
    for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < _cols; j++)
         _pixels[i][j] = new RGBColor(pixels[i][j]);    
}



 public void shiftCol (int offset)
{
    if(_offset == 0)
        _offset = offset;
    else
        _offset += offset;

    int currentShift = 1;

    if( (_offset == _cols) || (-_offset == _cols) ){
        makeBlack(_rows,_cols); //make black
    }    
    else if( (_offset < _cols) || (-_offset < _cols) )
    {
        if(_offset > 0){
            for(int j = currentShift; j < _cols && j <= _offset; j++){
                for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++){
                    setPixel(i,j + 1,this._pixels[i][j]);
                    setPixel(i,j,this._pixels[i][j] = new RGBColor());
                }    
            }
            _offset++;
            currentShift++;
        }
        else if(offset < 0){
            offset = -offset;
            for(int j = currentShift; j < _cols && j <= offset; j++){
                for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++){
                    setPixel(i,_cols - 1 - j,this._pixels[i][_cols - j]);
                    setPixel(i,_cols,this._pixels[i][_cols - j] = new RGBColor());
                }
                currentShift++;
            }   
        } 
    } 
}
public void setPixel(int row, int col, RGBColor pixel)
{
    if ((pixel != null) && (row < _pixels.length) && (col < _pixels[0].length))
        _pixels[row][col] = new RGBColor(pixel);
}

public String toString()
{
    String pixelSet ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < _rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < _cols; j++){
            pixelSet += this._pixels[i][j].toString();
        }
        pixelSet += "\n";
    }
    //pixelSet += tester;
    return pixelSet;
} 

}
```

and my Output tester class:

StudentTester class:

public class StudentTester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Black Image Constructor:");
    RGBImage rgbImg0 = new RGBImage(3,4);       
    System.out.println(rgbImg0);    

    System.out.println("Constructor with RGBColor[][] Array Parameter:");
    RGBColor[][] rgbArray1 = new RGBColor[5][4];
    for (int i=0; i<rgbArray1.length;i++)
        for (int j=0; j<rgbArray1[0].length;j++)    
            rgbArray1[i][j] = new RGBColor(i,i,i);                      
    RGBImage rgbImg1 = new RGBImage(rgbArray1);
    System.out.println(rgbImg1);

    System.out.println("Copy Constructor:");
    RGBImage rgbImg2 = new RGBImage(rgbImg1);
    System.out.println(rgbImg2);

    System.out.println("flipVertical:");
    rgbImg1.flipVertical();
    System.out.println(rgbImg1);

    System.out.println("rotateClockwise:");
    rgbImg1.rotateClockwise();
    System.out.println(rgbImg1);

    System.out.println("shiftCol 2:");
    rgbImg1.shiftCol(3);
    System.out.println(rgbImg1);

    System.out.println("shiftCol 2:");
    rgbImg1.shiftCol(-2);
    System.out.println(rgbImg1);

    System.out.println("shiftCol 2:");
    rgbImg1.shiftCol(1);
    System.out.println(rgbImg1);
}
```

}

Comment: This is just a guess because there is a lot of code to take in here.  But I think your for loop is only iterating the offset amount but it probably should be (offset * _cols)

Comment: @chancea Well, I'm trying to somehow determine WHICH columns shouldn't be moved, for example in ShiftCol +2 I don't want third and fourth to move, I just wanted them to be replaced by first and second columns. and the if I move ShiftCol - 1, I want just the second, third and fourth columns move one to the left. I believe I'm pretty close to the solution. I'll see what I can I do. also I find it hard to see how offset * _cols will help and where exactly.

Comment: I think the confusion is the word "columns" vs "_cols".  I think when you are saying "column" you mean the 3 columns a set makes up (the 3 set columns make up 1 full column).  I think it looks like in your code you are moving each set column over to the next position in the set, or is your current code actually moving it over to the next (offset amount) set?  Sorry if I am not making sense..

Comment: My code in ShiftCol when the offset is positive ( > 0) is moving the whole column set to the right as long as j < offset.

Comment: aha `setPixel(i,j + 1,this._pixels[i][j + 1]);` that line is doing nothing currently but setting the same pixel to the same pixel.  I think you want `setPixel(i,j + 1,this._pixels[i][j]);`

Comment: If I moved twice to the right, now I want to call ShiftCol method again and move one more to the right, it won't move the third column to the right because it will exit the loop because j < offset will become false after it moves the first column. which means I'll need somehow to remember if it already move and then move accordingly again.

Comment: Yup, it's a bit better now with that. but still not good enough. the first column set isn't moved to the fifth column. it is turned black before it can copy itself to the fifth column I believe.

Comment: @chancea I've edited the post with a newer code, trying to implement the offset in such a way that it will be used as a counter to remember which offset was the last and somehow will continue to shift if possible.

Comment: You should give the full code of RGBImage, at least as far as the definitions of the fields. Rule: you have to give the definition of any variable or method that you use, and all the places that change them.

Comment: @RealSkeptic With pleasure. just added three fields. I don't see anything else that is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public void shiftCol (int offset)
{
    if(offset > 0){
       for(int j = _cols - 1; j >= 0; j--){
          for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++){
              if (j - offset >= 0) 
                  _pixels[i][j] = _pixels[i][j-offset];
              else
                  _pixels[i][j] = new RGBColor();                    
          }    
       }
    } else {
       for(int j = 0; j <=_cols - 1; j++){
          for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++){
              if (j - offset < _cols) 
                 _pixels[i][j] = _pixels[i][j-offset];
              else
                 _pixels[i][j] = new RGBColor();                   
          }    
       }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't really need the `_offset` field. The only place you are using it is the `shiftCol()` method, and it is not really a part of the state of the image as an object. It should therefore be a local variable. But really, the parameter `offset` is doing the job quite well, you don't need an extra variable. Remember, parameters are passed by value, even if you change the value of `offset`, it's not going to change anything in the calling code.

Second, you really don't need the variable `currentShift`, either. You are adding one to it, but the first `currentShift++` is not in a loop and there is no further use of it, and the second `currentShift++` is in a loop, but it doesn't affect anything in the loop and is not used after it. So - get rid of it.

Now, to your real problem. Let's look at the positive offset first. What you do for each column is:

- Put the value of the pixel in the pixel to its right
- Change the current value of the pixel to black - *twice* (first by setting it directly in the `_pixels[i][j]` and then again by the call to `setPixel()`).

This has several problems. First, since you run with `j` from `0` to `offset`, what happens is this:

- The pixel that was in column 0 is placed in column 1, and column 0 is blackened.
- The pixel that is in column 1 (which we actually changed in the previous step) is placed in column 2, and column 1 is blackened.
- Then the pixel is moved to column 3, and so on.

Why all these moves of one pixel? And the creation of a new pixel object each time you do it.

And you just moved a single column, destroying all the column values along the way. Doing so, you lost all the information in them that should have also been moved!

And then, of course, the double assignment of new objects, one of which goes straight to the garbage.

Now to untangle this knot.

As a rule, when you copy a portion of an array onto itself, it's always important to copy in the right order. Let's look at a simple array of characters:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│A│B│C│D│E│F│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

Suppose you want to move the "BCD" part two spaces to the right, so that the result would be "ABCBCD" (not caring about erasing the moved part at the moment). Naively, you think that moving:

```
arr[3] = arr[1];
arr[4] = arr[2];
arr[5] = arr[3];
```

is going to do the right thing. but in fact, what you get is:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│A│B│C│B│C│B│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

Why is there a "B" in position 5? Because we have already changed `arr[3]` in our first assignment. Doing that destroyed the `D`, so when we come to assign `arr[3]` to `arr[5]`, it's already "B".

The correct way to copy to the right is therefore to start from the right:

```
arr[5] = arr[3];
arr[4] = arr[2];
arr[3] = arr[1];
```

But... if we wanted to shift left, doing it in the reverse order like that would not work. Start again from our original "ABCDEF". Suppose we want to shift the "CDE" 2 positions to the left to get "CDEDEF". If we do it in reverse:

```
arr[2] = arr[4];
arr[1] = arr[3];
arr[0] = arr[2];
```

Then again, we get:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│E│D│E│D│E│F│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

Because `arr[2]` was already changed when we got to it.

**Conclusion:**

1. To shift part of an array to the right, you have to start your loop from the high indexes and go down to the low indexes.
2. To shift part of an array to the left, you have to start your loop from the low indexes and go up to the high indexes.

Also note that there is no point in moving the block one place and then one more place etc. - it just wastes time (and memory if you create new objects). You should shift it directly to where it is supposed to be. If you are supposed to move it by 2, then its new index is `j+2`.

Now, let's suppose our array is like the rows in your problem. We want to shift all the contents, not just part, and fill in with blanks.

So if I want to shift this array 2 positions to the right:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│A│B│C│D│E│F│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

I expect to get:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│ │ │A│B│C│D│
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

I now know I have to start on the right to do it correctly. What I do is look at each position from 5 down to 0, and think: what is the source for this position? It's supposed to be the cell such that I'm currently two positions to the right of. That is, the cell that's two position to my left. Is there such a cell? If so, put its value in the current index. If not (because the source position is negative), then I fill in with a blank:

```
for ( i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    if ( i - offset >= 0 ) {
        arr[i] = arr[i-offset];
    } else {
        arr[i] = ' ';
    }
}
```

If you got the idea, you'll now be able to apply what I did with the array of characters to your row of pixels.

Your next task should be applying the reverse logic to negative offsets (remember, left to right!)

One final note: don't use `setPixel()` for this copy operation. It creates new pixel objects, and that's really unnecessary (except for the black parts). I suppose `setPixel()` does that because it's a public method and gives a protective copy of the pixel so that if its contents are changed it won't affect our image. But for an internal operation, that's not necessary.

Comment: What a wonderful answer @realSkeptic ! I will update you tomorrow with what I've tried! Thank you so much!! It's awesome to understand how to approach coding it. Thank you very much again!